# -[__NSCFSet _isNaturallyRTL]- error

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsstring, uitextfield

.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *responsibleField;
```

.m

```
@synthesize responsibleField;


responsibleField.text = [goal valueForKeyPath:@"responsibility.actorNaam"];
```

and actorNaam is of type String in my datamodel ..
and my textfield is correctly connected

Error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFSet _isNaturallyRTL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e8e9d0'

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object at `goal.responsibility` is an NSSet, invoking `valueForKeyPath:` on an NSSet returns an NSSet of the values at the specified keypaths.

If you just want to "pick one" from the set, use this:

```
[ [ goal valueForKeyPath:@"responsibility.actorNaam" ] anyObject ] ;
```

i.e. the question is **which** responsibility do you want?

Answer (score 1):

`[goal valueForKeyPath:@"responsibility.actorNaam"];` is returning an object of type `NSSet` `responsibleField.text` is expecting an `NSString`. Check your code where you set the value for key path `responsibility.actorNaam`.

Comment: close--it's because of goal.responsibility is a set, and invoking valueWithKeyPath on a set (as in this case)--this always returns a set of the values at the specified keyPath. This will work: `[ goal valueForKeyPath:@"responsibility.actorNaam" ] anyObject ]`

Comment: Thanks, will this also work when responsibility is a to-many relationship ?